# error generating the XML document - Workday WebAPI

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-serialization, workday-api

When calling a [Workday API Assign_Costing_Allocation](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Payroll/v29.2/Assign_Costing_Allocation.html) there is suddenly an XML generation error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=There was an error in serializing body of message Assign_Costing_AllocationInput: 'There was an error generating the XML document.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at PostBudget.PayrollService.PayrollPort.Assign_Costing_Allocation(Assign_Costing_AllocationInput request)
...
Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: The type PostBudget.PayrollService.Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectIDType was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
```

PostBudget.PayrollService.Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectIDType is supplied in References.cs, auto-generated and has the serialization tags:

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
public partial class Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectIDType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }
```

How to debug this? What can I do to make this work?

Comment: I assume the code was working.  I suspect there is an issue with the proxy.  The date of the certificate may of expired.  Check in you IE the certficates and see if any of them expired.  Does the URL work if you use an IE to go to the site?

Comment: @jdweng the object at fault is actually part of the bigger object being serialized. Corrected the question. No, it wasn't working in this configuration. If I remove  Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectIDType instance, everything does work.

Comment: The code looks like it is getting a proxy error.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see if the app is attempting to communicate with the proxy server.  You will either see a request being sent to a proxy and no response with will indicating the proxy isn't running (or maybe you are using wrong ip), or you will get a response and then maybe the response will indicate the real root cause of the error.

Comment: It does not approach communication part. The error is in converting the payload object to XML. Request fails before an outgoing message is created.

Comment: You cannot create the xml without the first connecting to the proxy server to get the key from the proxy.   That is what the exception message is stating.  The soap xml contains an encryption section and that is where the failure is occurring.  I don't know if the connection is wrong or the certificate on your PC is expired.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in References.cs, generated from the WSDL, listing incorrect type Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectType, instead of Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectIDType where an Tenanted_Payroll_WorktagObjectIDType is required.  Manually changing the auto-generated file fixed the issue.